# how to replace dtype=K.floatx()?

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, keras, sentiment-analysis

I am very much new to python and I am trying to understand the following code snippet, but I don't know actually what is being done for train test split and also I am having a problem with Keras. can anyone make me understand what is happening in there and is there any replacement for `dtype=K.floatx()`?

```
import keras.backend as K

train_size = int(0.9*(len(tweets)))
test_size = int(0.1*(len(tweets)))

max_no_tokens = 15

indexes = set(np.random.choice(len(tweets), train_size + test_size, replace=False))

x_train = np.zeros((train_size, max_no_tokens, vector_size), dtype=K.floatx())
y_train = np.zeros((train_size, 2), dtype=np.int32)

x_test = np.zeros((test_size, max_no_tokens, vector_size), dtype=K.floatx())
y_test = np.zeros((test_size, 2), dtype=np.int32)
```

Comment: Why do you want to replace K.floatx()?

Comment: because I am having CPU version of Keras installed with TensorFlow backend. still, when I run "import Keras", it gives me a long error. and I tried many methods but I could not resolve that.